# saving JFrame as image file (.JPG, .PNG, .BMP etc)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, screenshot

There is a `JFrame` with `JPanel` `DefaultTableModel` with `JScrollPane`. How to save the entire `JFrame` to an image file?

Answer (score 2):

`ImageIO` class will help you. The signature of the method you need is:

```
public static boolean write(RenderedImage im, String formatName, File output)
```

Determine image extension **(.jpg, .png, .bmp etc)** via `formatName` parameter. For more information take a look at this post:

http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.awt/how-to-capture-screenshot.html